# Facebook login with Python Requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, facebook, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to login to Facebook using the Python Requests- and BeautifulSoup modules (just as an exercise), and I'm having some problems with finding the POST parameters to send to the server.

The first thing I did was that I identified the POST parameters I would need to send by manually login into Facebook in a browser:
[image: description here]

Then I wrote some code to get the Facebook front page and extract values from the login form fields:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/', headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'})
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

login_params = {
    'email': 'myemail@something.com',
    'pass': 'mypassword',
    'default_persistent': bs.select('input[name=default_persistent]')[0].get('value'),
    #'lgndim': bs.select('input[name=lgndim]')[0].get('value'),  #Empty value attribute.
    #'lgnjs': bs.select('input[name=lgnjs]')[0].get('value'),  #This one has value="n" for some reason.
    'lgnrnd': bs.select('input[name=lgnrnd]')[0].get('value'),
    'locale': bs.select('input[name=locale]')[0].get('value'),
    'lsd': bs.select('input[name=lsd]')[0].get('value'),
    #'qsstamp': bs.select('input[name=qsstamp]')[0].get('value'),  #This one isn't found at all.
    #'timezone': bs.select('#u_0_w')[0].get('value'),  #Empty value attribute.
}
```

The parameters that are commented out are the ones I'm having trouble with. I can retrieve those input elements (except one), but the problem is that their value attributes are empty or wrong. Let's take the parameter "lgndim" as an example. When I select it with BeautifulSoup in my script I get this:

```
input autocomplete="off" id="u_0_y" name="lgndim" type="hidden" value=""
```

But when I write the request text into a html file likes this:

```
with open('hello.htm', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

and view the input element in my browser it looks like this:

```
input autocomplete="off" name="lgndim" value="eyJ3IjoyNTYwLCJoIjoxNDQwLCJhdyI6MjU2MCwiYWgiOjE0MDAsImMiOjI0fQ==" id="u_0_y" type="hidden"
```

Anyone know what's wrong here? I'm completely stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope I gave enough information.

Comment: Facebook does not want you (and others) to log into their page in an automated way. The all kind of tricks to prevent that. To access their data they offer several APIs and also a Python library.

Comment: Do you think Facebook made these input values difficult to access to thwart scripts like this? Also, what can you do with these kind of automated scripts that they are afraid of?

Comment: Sport, but what I think is out of the scope of SO. No option based questions. For more information read the Facebook developer documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get some `hidden` inputs ant it's values, because in browser it's created and filled with JavaScript, though you can discover their values reverse engineering scripts on page or using non-browser JavaScript engines like phantomjs.

But to login you don't need to do that, you just need to extract single cookie that served by scripts — `datr` or `_js_datr`, and it's possible using regex:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
def facebook_login(mail, pwd):
    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.get('https://www.facebook.com/', allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    action_url = soup.find('form', id='login_form')['action']
    inputs = soup.find('form', id='login_form').findAll('input', {'type': ['hidden', 'submit']})
    post_data = {input.get('name'): input.get('value')  for input in inputs}
    post_data['email'] = mail
    post_data['pass'] = pwd.upper()
    scripts = soup.findAll('script')
    scripts_string = '/n/'.join([script.text for script in scripts])
    datr_search = re.search('\["_js_datr","([^"]*)"', scripts_string, re.DOTALL)
    if datr_search:
        datr = datr_search.group(1)
        cookies = {'_js_datr' : datr}
    else:
        return False
    return session.post(action_url, data=post_data, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=False)
```

And if you check this function output:

```
>>> facebook_login('mama@home', 'greatpancake')
<Response [302]>
```

Response status `302 Found` means you were logged in and redirected.

Comment: Cool, so by sending this 'datr' cookie I can bypass the need of filling out those empty POST parameter. But why does that work and how was I supposed to figure that out?

Comment: @Justsomeguy, well, cookies served by JavaScript is rather usual way to make login security more complex. I've discovered that during reverse engineering login process using developer tools in browser. You can just view network log and play with something like `curl` excluding request parameters one-by-one and trying to reproduce expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
#IMPORTS
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#CONSTRAINTS
EMAIL = your_email
PASSW = your_password
LOGIN_URL = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2F&amp;refid=8"
FACEBOOK_URL = "http://www.facebook.com"

#VARS
s = None

#MAIN CLASS
class facebook():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = requests.session()
        self.login()
        self.find_accounts_by_name()

    def login(self):
        #GET DEFAULT VALUES FROM PAGE
        r = self.s.get(FACEBOOK_URL, verify=False)
        print r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
        #GET DEFAULT VALUES
        tmp = soup.find(attrs={"name": "lsd"})
        lsd = tmp["value"]

        data = {
            'lsd': lsd
        }
        data['email'] = EMAIL
        data['pass'] = PASSW
        data['login'] = 'Log In'

        r = self.s.post(LOGIN_URL , data=data, verify=False)
        print r.text
```